# Changing the number of columns in kendo UI grid based on JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a rails app that is using a Kendo UI grid.  The grid displays information for different marketing campaign objects, and each campaign has a different amount of weeks to it.  In the grid each week of a campaign is a column.  So what I need to do is based on the amount of weeks for a given campaign I need to have that many columns in the grid.  So if a a campaign has 6 weeks the grid needs to 6 columns, if it has 10 weeks it needs to have 10 columns.  The data is coming back as a json string, below is an example of the formatted json that is read in through the read method of the kendo transporter.

```
"[{\"week_1\":\"2014-06-17\"},{\"week_2\":\"2014-06-17\"},{\"week_3\":\"2014-06-24\"},{\"week_4\":\"2014-06-24\"},{\"week_5\":\"2014-07-01\"},{\"week_6\":\"2014-07-01\"}]"
```

I have been searching around for a while trying to figure out how to do this with kendo and have not found a good example, any pointers/examples would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You need to programmatically generate the `columns` definition depending on the received data and before creating the `Grid`. How are the weeks received from the server (different fields name, JSON array,...)? Could you edit the original question and include an example of the JSON received? Is the Grid editable?

Comment: Why are you making something that should be rows into columns? Does it really have to be that way?\

Comment: @OnaBai I added the json string that is returned to the question.  This is going to be the first row in a Hierarchy grid that will be editable.  Is there a way to iterate over the json in the columns portion of the grid?  I really appreciate you helping me out.